# append text from input and submit form

Tags: jquery

I have  a situation where I need to append text on submitting the form. Just when the user submits the form need to append text from hidden input value to text area with user type content and appended url to last.

```
<form action="http://domain.com/index.php" method="post" name="contact_form"  id="contact_form">

            <input id="yourName" type="text" name="yourName" value="">                                
            <input id="yourEmail" type="text" name="yourEmail" value="">                                
            <input id="phoneNumber" type="text" name="phoneNumber" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="fromurl" value="http://www.google.com" id="fromurl">
            <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="10"></textarea>
            <button type="submit">Send</button>

            </form>

<script type="text/javascript">(function($) {
$("form#contact_form").submit(function() {
    value = $("#fromurl").val(); 


    $('#message').text(value);

   });
})(jQuery);</script>
```

but it doesnot show the appended url when somebody types and clicks submit.

ok I have edited without prevent default.

Comment: if you want to submit the form why are you calling `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: also calling `$("#contact_form").submit();` creates a infinite recursive method... remove that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this updated answer. just change val and text to html, first check their is value in formurl or not by console print.

```
  (function ($) {
    $("form#contact_form").submit(function (event) {
    var value = $("#fromurl").val();
    console.log(value);
    //Use .val() to set the value of textarea
    console.log(" textarea "+$('#message').val());
    $('#message').val($('#message').val()+value);

});
})(jQuery);
```

check this [jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/patelbharat001/Lq9L9ebd/3/)

Comment: sorry it didnot work ,can you show it in jsfiddle pls

Comment: I see the value is printed in log but its not attached to text area, I want the text area txt and #fromurl value to be send when clicking submit

Comment: @user9912 sorry for last answer, check updated answer, In demo i have added return false, to prevent form submit, but you did not need it. so remove it for actual use.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(function ($) {
    $("form#contact_form").submit(function (event) {
        //there is no need for this as you want to submit the form
        //event.preventDefault();

        var value = $("#fromurl").val();
        //Use .val() to set the value of textarea
        $('#message').val(value);

        //this will create a recursive call to the submit handler, not need for this either
        //$("#contact_form").submit();

    });
})(jQuery);
```